# How to add refresh token logic to RxJava+Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm new in RxJava, but I like it. And now I have little problem. 
I'm using `RxJava` + `Retrofit`.

If I have valid token for user, I get response for API, but if token is invalid, I must refresh token and try make request again.

**Valid token:**

1. Make reuqest
2. Get response
3. Done

**Invalid token:**

1. Make request
2. Get response
3. `If` `response_code == 403`, need refresh token
4. Refresh token
5. Here I want go to 1 step and make request to API again
6. `Else` - done

**How to make it using RxJava?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one has my knowledge

```
service.normalRequest()
            .flatMap( new Func1<Response, Observable<Response>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Response> call(Response response) {
                    if (response.code() == 403) {
                        return service.refreshToken(refreshRequest)
                                .flatMap(new Func1<Response, Observable<Response>>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Observable<Response> call(Response response) {
                                        return service.normalRequest();
                                    }
                                });

                    } else {
                        return Observable.just(response);
                    }

                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(
                new Subscriber<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response response) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a special operator that can be used in this case:

[`public final Observable<T> retryWhen(final Func1<? super Observable<? extends Throwable>, ? extends Observable<?>> notificationHandler)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L9063)

If you implement it you will see what parameters it accepts:

```
observable.retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<T>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(final Observable<? extends Throwable> error) {

     }
});
```

You can see, that you get the error that was thrown by OkHttp. It is always throwing `HttpException`, if you call:

```
httpException.code()
```

You will get HTTP code number.

So the implementation of the function above might look like:

```
observable.retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<T>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<T> call(final Observable<? extends Throwable> error) {
             return error.flatMap(doRelogging());
         }
    });
```

I have made a small library, that does what you expect:

[RetrofitRxErrorHandler](https://github.com/RobertZagorski/RetrofitRxErrorHandler)

You might try it or just look into sources for more advanced retry strategies regarding fetching API errors.