# How to make another api call only if 1st api call fails using retrofit rxjava

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am new to retrofit and rxjava. I am trying to achieve a very common use case using these 2 but not able to find the right operators to do. Use Case - I am making an API call to check if my access token is valid or not. If it is no more valid i get 401 unauthorized exception, at this point i want to make an API call to fetch new access token using refresh token. 
Note - The response type for both the API requests is different.

How can i achieve this using retrofit and rxjava.

I tried achieving it using flatMap, onErrorResume but not able to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970191/4643073

Comment: Hi @Tuby I tried the solution. It does not work in my case because for validation request i get okhttp3.Response and for refresh token request i get custom LoginResponse in which i get my new accesstoken value. The solution you provided works fine if the response for both the requests is same. Can you please suggest a workaround for this.

Comment: Thanks @Tuby Played around a bit with the solution you provided and issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
requestApi.checkAccessToken(accessToken).flatMap(
     object : Function<Response, Observable<Response>> {
         override fun apply(t: Response): Observable<Response> {
            if (t.code() === 400) {
              return requestApi.getAccessToken(refreshToken,"refreshToken").flatMap(
               object : Function<LoginResponse, Observable<Response>> {
                 override fun apply(t: LoginResponse): Observable<Response> {
                        return requestApi.checkAccessToken(t.access_token)
            }
          })
       } else {
          return Observable.just(t)
       }
    }
 }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(this::handleAccessTokenResponse, this::handleError)
```