# Calling request inside http interceptor causing problems

Tags: android, httpclient, access-token

I am trying to handle code 401 that could happen when token expired for any reason

```
public class AuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {


@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    AtomicReference<Response> response = new AtomicReference<>(chain.proceed(request));
    if (response.get().code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED && response.get().message().equals("Unauthorized")) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (response.get().code() == 401) {
                deleteCurrentToken();
                BaseResponse<RefreshTokenResponse> refreshTokenResponse = new RefreshTokenApi().call().blockingGet();
                String newToken = refreshTokenResponse.getResponse().header("Authorization");
                saveToken(newToken);
                request.newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", PreferencesWrapperImpl.SINGLETON.getStringForKey(Constants.PreferenceKey.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, "")).build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        }
    }

    return response.get();
}

private synchronized void deleteCurrentToken() {
    PreferencesWrapperImpl.SINGLETON.putStringForKey(null, Constants.PreferenceKey.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
}

private synchronized void saveToken(String newToken) {
    PreferencesWrapperImpl.SINGLETON.putStringForKey(newToken, Constants.PreferenceKey.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
}
```

}

so here i intercept the request if it's code is 401 i call refresh token request then update the token shared preference and i make everything synchronized even call refresh token with blocking get to handle multi requests

then after updating the token i wanna proceed the first request with new token, but when i debug i couldn't get the line after refresh token request and intercept function keep calling

Comment: Hey @karim, if you are using RxJava, there is a special function 'retryWhen' for this requirement. Check this out -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969754/how-to-add-refresh-token-logic-to-rxjavaretrofit

Comment: @AnujSharma but i don't think  retrywhen handle multi requesting

Comment: You can chain as many API you want in RxJava won't be an issue.

Comment: how, is there full example @AnujSharma